# mod_rewrite to give PHP get parameters doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why is this `mod_rewrite` not working?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_-]+)(|)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ index.php?url=news&id=$1 [NC]
```

Here's the **PHP code** for handling the loading of the news:

```
<?php
$sql = DB::Query("SELECT id,title,longstory FROM news WHERE id = ".filter($_GET['id'])."");
if(DB::NumRows($sql) == 1)
{
    while($news = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">
                '.$news["title"].'
            </div>
            <div class="mainBox newsBox" style="float;left">
                <div class="boxHeader"></div>
                '.html_entity_decode($news['longstory']).'
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
} else
{
    ?>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='title red'>Artikel is niet gevonden.</div>
        <div class='mainBox'>
            Jammer genoeg is dit nieuws artikel niet gevonden!
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

If I use http://127.0.0.1/index.php?url=news&id=48 it's working, but http://127.0.0.1/news/48 doesn't, even though I have added the `mod_rewrite` rule in my `.htaccess`.

Comment: Is your web server using Linux?

Comment: if you got 404 , Try something like this in your main `httpd.conf` file: `<Directory "/path/to/your/site">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

Answer (score 2):

your first rule does match the `/news/48` pattern as well, change the order of the rules and put the specific one `^news/(.*)$` first